# Vertically center equation number in aligned equation

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment

I have these aligned equations for which I would like to have a single equation number. I found that this can be simply solved by embedding an `aligned` environment in an `equation`, but now I have on formula for which the last line is too long to add an equation number to the right. This causes the equation number, which would actually fit nicely to the right if vertically centred, to be wrapped below the equation.

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{E}
\newcommand{\with}{\;;}
\newcommand{\dx}[1]{\mathop{\mathrm{d}#1}}
\newcommand{\expect}[2][]{\E_{#1} \left[#2\right]}

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        \mu_{D_-} & = \expect{f'(S_-) \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{N} W D} \\
        & = N \mu_W \mu_D \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f'(s) p_\mathcal{N}(s \with \mu_{S_-}, \sigma_{S_-}) \dx{s} \\
        \sigma_{D_-}^2 & = \expect{f'(S_-)^2 \cdot \left(\sum_{i=1}^{N} W D\right)^2} - \mu_{D_-}^2 \\
        & = N \left(\sigma_W^2 \sigma_D^2 + \mu_W^2 \sigma_D^2 + \sigma_W^2 \mu_D^2 + N \mu_W^2 \mu_D^2\right) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f'(s)^2 p_\mathcal{N}(s \with \mu_{S_-}, \sigma_{S_-}) \dx{s} - \mu_{D_-}^2 \,.
    \end{aligned}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

It just bothers me slightly and I was wondering whether there is a way to force a vertically centred equation number in this case. I found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180406/split-environment-not-vertically-centering-equation-number), but all of the things that I have tried to shorten that expression were unsuccessful. I also would like to keep the last expression on one line to stay consistent with the rest of my document.

Is there any way to force the equation number vertically centred to the right, although my last expression is too long? Or any trick to make the equation believe that the `aligned` part is not as long as it actually is, so that the equation number appears vertically centred on the right (above the equation that would be too long)?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! You could find a lot of questions like this here. Have a look at: [How to align a set of multiline equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44451/124842) , [How can I split an equation over two (or more) lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3785/124842),

Comment: @Bobyandbob I know that I could split the line, but I hoped I could leave the last line as it is, because the equation number would fit above it. I'll edit my question to make this more clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a case where visual formatting seems necessary, so it should be dealt with only in the very last stage of document preparation.

You can pretend that the very last part of the formula “is not there”:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{E}
\newcommand{\with}{\,;}
\newcommand{\dx}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\expect}[2][]{\E\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else_{#1}\fi \left[#2\right]}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\mu_{D_-}
  &= \expect{f'(S_-) \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{N} W D} \\
  &= N \mu_W \mu_D \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f'(s) p_\mathcal{N}(s \with \mu_{S_-}, \sigma_{S_-}) \dx{s} \\
\sigma_{D_-}^2
  &= \expect{f'(S_-)^2 \cdot \left(\sum_{i=1}^{N} W D\right)^2} - \mu_{D_-}^2 \\
  &= N(\sigma_W^2 \sigma_D^2 + \mu_W^2 \sigma_D^2 + \sigma_W^2 \mu_D^2 + N \mu_W^2 \mu_D^2)
       \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f'(s)^2 p_\mathcal{N}(s \with \mu_{S_-}, \sigma_{S_-}) \dx{s}
    \mathrlap{{} - \mu_{D_-}^2 \,.}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I amended your definition of `\dx`, because it would give wrong spacing on the right. Also `\;` seems too big for `\with` (to be honest, I wouldn't add a space before the semicolon).

Your definition of `\expect` with automatic `\left` and `\right` produces too big delimiters in many cases (see the third line, for instance).

Here's an amended version that uses `xparse` and `mathtools` features; the syntax for `\expect` is

```
\expect{formula}
\expect[\big]{formula}
\expect*{formula}

\expect_{sub}{formula}
\expect_{sub}[\big]{formula}
\expect_{sub}*{formula}
```

as shown in the added equation. In the optional argument one can use `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg` or `\Bigg`; the *-version uses `\left` and `\right`.

Note also the addition of `\,` and `\!` in a few places.

[image]

Comment: Hi, very good. I like much your picture created with mac retina :-) monitor. Good work +1.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the  `\mathrlap` solution, you have the possibility to replace `aligned` with `split` and use the `\raisetag` command. I took the liberty to adjust manually the size of a couple of delimiters and the placement of an exponent:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{E}
\newcommand{\with}{\;;}
\newcommand{\dx}[1]{\mathop{\mathrm{d}#1}}
\newcommand{\expect}[2][]{\E_{#1} \left[#2\right]}

\begin{document}

  \begin{equation}
    \begin{split}\raisetag{15ex}
        \mu_{D_-} & = \expect{f'(S_-) \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{N} W D} \\
        & = N \mu_W \mu_D \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f'(s) p_\mathcal{N}(s \with \mu_{S_-}, \sigma_{S_-}) \dx{s} \\
        \sigma_{D_-}^2 & = \expect{f'(S_-)^2 \cdot \biggl(\sum_{i=1}^{N} W D\biggr)^{\!\!2}} - \mu_{D_-}^2 \\
        & = N \bigl(\sigma_W^2 \sigma_D^2 + \mu_W^2 \sigma_D^2 + \sigma_W^2 \mu_D^2 + N \mu_W^2 \mu_D^2\bigr) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f'(s)^2 p_\mathcal{N}(s \with \mu_{S_-}, \sigma_{S_-}) \dx{s} - \mu_{D_-}^2 \,.
    \end{split}
  \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

last line of your equation is to long for text width, so equation number is pushed below equation. split this line into two lines:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{E}
\newcommand{\with}{\;;}
\newcommand{\dx}[1]{\mathop{\mathrm{d}#1}}
\newcommand{\expect}[2][]{\E_{#1} \left[#2\right]}

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        \mu_{D_-} & = \expect{f'(S_-) \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{N} W D} \\
        & = N \mu_W \mu_D \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f'(s) p_\mathcal{N}(s \with \mu_{S_-}, \sigma_{S_-}) \dx{s} \\
        \sigma_{D_-}^2 & = \expect{f'(S_-)^2 \cdot \left(\sum_{i=1}^{N} W D\right)^2} - \mu_{D_-}^2 \\
        & = \begin{multlined}[t][0.6\linewidth] % defined in mathtools
        N \left(\sigma_W^2 \sigma_D^2 + \mu_W^2 \sigma_D^2 + \sigma_W^2 \mu_D^2 + N \mu_W^2 \mu_D^2\right) \cdot\\[1ex]
        \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f'(s)^2 p_\mathcal{N}(s \with \mu_{S_-}, \sigma_{S_-}) \dx{s} - \mu_{D_-}^2    \,.
        \end{multlined}
    \end{aligned}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I actually hoped to find a solution where I could leave the last expression on one line and force the equation number to appear to the right. I have edited my question to make this more clear.